# Expected property "0" of type ECPair, got p

Tags: bitcoin-core, blockchain, bip32-hd-wallets

When I'm trying to create a wallet in react app using the following code:

```
const seed = bip39.mnemonicToSeed(mnemonic);
const master = bitcoin.HDNode.fromSeedBuffer(seed, "testnet");
```

I got `error: Expected property "0" of type ECPair, got p`

Answer (score 2):

> HDNode was removed and is now a separated package.
>
> npm install bip32 See [Issue #1243](https://github.com/bitcoinjs/bitcoinjs-lib/issues/1243#issuecomment-429627079)

```
const bitcoin = require('bitcoinjs-lib')
const bip39 = require('bip39')
const bip32 = require('bip32')

const mnemonic = 'praise you muffin lion enable neck grocery crumble super myself license ghost'
const seed = bip39.mnemonicToSeed(mnemonic)
const node = bip32.fromSeed(seed)
```

Test examples: [bitcoinjs-lib tests](https://github.com/bitcoinjs/bitcoinjs-lib/blob/master/test/integration/bip32.js#L19)